# Transit visa in Hong kong

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, hong-kong

I am going from India to Japan. I have Japan visa. My flight is via Hong kong.
Transit time is around 5 hours. Is it required to have Hong kong visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting this information into TIMATIC (the database used by airlines):

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward (Air-to-Air or Air-to-Sea) ticket to a third country within 48 hours. They must stay in the international transit area and have documents required for the next destination.

That means if you don’t leave the transit area to:

- exit the airport
- pass through immigration
- don’t recheck luggage

Then you don’t need a visa.